# How to calculate coordinates in radians

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a line from `(1,0)` to `(cos (pi/4), sin (pi/4))`.

I would like LaTeX to make the calculations using radians if possible.

Answer (score 12):

You can convert from radians to degrees using the `r` function:

```
\draw (1,0) -- ({cos(pi/4 r)}, {sin(pi/4 r)});
```

Answer (score 5):

You can specify polar coordinates using

```
(<angle>:<radius>)
```

Here is the code with an unitary grey circle to help with coordinates. The `x` is the origin.

[image]

**Code**

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[gray] (0,0)node{$\times$} circle (1cm);
\draw (1,0)--(45:1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: +1, I'm almost sure that this is what Mark should actually be using.