# problem when using radians with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath, pgfmathparse, xfp

My initial problem occurred with this code:

```
\def\a{pi/2}
\pgfmathparse{\a r}\pgfmathresult
output : 89.99937
```

When I modified the macro `\a` thus `\def\a{pi}`

I get the error: Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function 'pir' (in 'pir').
In this case an unsatisfactory solution is  `\def\a{pi/1}`

Also possible

```
\edef\tp{\noexpand \pgfmathparse{pi r}}\tp%
\pgfmathresult

output: 179.99962
```

The problem also arises when trying to modify this Jake code in [how to calculate coordinates in radians](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229765/how-to-calculate-coordinates-in-radians).

Jake gives this answer :

```
\tikz \draw (1,0) -- ({cos(pi/4 r)}, {sin(pi/4 r)});
```

but

```
\def\a{pi}
 \tikz \draw (1,0) -- ({cos(\a r)}, {sin(\a r)});
```

presents the same problem.

The first question is:  how to avoid this problem simply? or how to convert radians to degrees in a safe way?

Another question is : is possible to use `xfp` to get the conversion or another tool ?

Comment: You need `\def\a{pi\space}`.

Comment: Yes I know but it's like `\def\a{pi/1}` (\space is better). Are there other possibilities?

Comment: There’s also the equivalent math function `deg`. I’m on mobile device, hence sorry I didn’t run tests before adding comments. Maybe related: https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/1077.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ yes `deg` is a possiblity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `\def\a{pi}`, `\pgfmathparse{\a r}` or `\draw (1,0) -- ({cos(\a r)}, {sin(\a r)})` will raise errors because i) `pgfmath` does `\edef` to the expression before parsing it and ii) the space after `\a`, a control word (a backslash followed by one or more characters with catcode 11), is skipped. Therefore the expression ready to be parsed always contain `pir`, not `pi r`.

In question comments,

- My first suggestion `\def\a{pi\space}` makes sure that after `\edef` a space is left in between `pi` and `r` (`\space` expands to a normal space char). Other tricks commonly used to reserve space char after a control word may *not work* here:

  - `\def\a{pi\ }` doesn't work because `\`  is not expandable and the `pgfmath` parser can't handler it.
  - `\def\a{pi}` with `\pgfmathparse{\a{} r}` doesn't work either because `{}` won't disappear after `\edef` and curly braces denote array-like structures in `pgfmath` expression.
- The second suggestion is replacing the postfix operator `r` with its function form `deg`: `cos(\a r)` -> `cos(deg(pi))`.

Here's a third one: You could define pseudo-constant as a zero-arg `pgfmath` function.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
% option 1
\tikzset{
  declare function={
    constA=pi;
  }
}

% option 2
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{constB}{0}{%
  \begingroup
    \pgfmathparse{pi}%
    \pgfmathreturn{\pgfmathresult pt}% assign to a length is the most robust way
  \endgroup%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\pgfmathprint{constA r},
\pgfmathprint{constB r}

\tikz \draw (1,0) -- ({cos(constA r)}, {sin(constB r)}) ;
\end{document}
```

Note if the function has a single-letter name, like `a` in `declare function={ a=pi; }`, then you'll encounter the not-yet resolved pgf issue https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/1077.

BTW, `\pgfmathparse` is not fully expandable, hence writing `\edef\tp{\pgfmathparse{...}}` is dangerous and there's no warranty that this `\edef` and the following use of `\tp` will work without errors in future versions.

---

> Another question is : is possible to use `xfp` to get the conversion or another tool ?

Yes it's possible. `xfp`'s `\fpeval` (or the equivalent latex3 function `\fp_eval:n`) is fully expandable (and sometimes more accurate than `pgfmath`), hence it's valid to use `\fpeval` in a `pgfmath` expression, except it's a bit strange.

LaTeX3 module `l3fp` defines `pi` as the normal 3.1415... constant, but `deg` as another *constant* denoting radians per degree. Therefore `\pgfmathprint{pi r}` and `\fpeval{pi/deg}` do the same radian-to-degree conversion.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfmath}
\usepackage{xfp}

\begin{document}
\def\a{pi}

\pgfmathprint{sin(\fpeval{\a/deg})}, % =  0.0
\pgfmathprint{cos(\fpeval{\a/deg})}  % = -1.0
\end{document}
```